# Can I install ubuntu 14.04 on my RAIDed desktop?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, raid

I think I heard that RAID was removed from the Ubuntu installer recently.

My system is currently made up of a series of RAID1 arrays: one for 12.04, with /home mounted on a separate partition/array. I have kept a spare partition/array for the next OS upgrade, which is now.

I would like to do a fresh installation in this blank spare partition, keeping the existing /home (I will use different user names to get a genuine fresh install) array.

Will I be able to do this?

Comment: I have the same problem. [" How can I create a software RAID drive and install Ubuntu Desktop on that drive?"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/993/how-can-i-create-a-software-raid-drive-and-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-that-drive) and [Ubuntu installation: Software RAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID)  mention an "alternate install disk", which worked fine for Ubuntu 12, but I can't seem to find it for Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Desktop Package of Ubuntu 14.04 does not allow for RAID installation I found the best route is to install the [Server Package of Ubuntu 14.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/) and add the ubuntu-desktop after.

Once partitioned, configured, and installed at a command line prompt you can enter the following to install ubuntu-desktop:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

When the installer finishes you will need to reboot. Do this by entering:

`sudo reboot now`

Source: [UbuntuLinuxGuide](http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/software-raid-ubuntu-14-04-setup-install-configure/)

Comment: I think I'll give this one a go!

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions at [Setting Up RAID During 13.04 Install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294746/setting-up-raid-during-13-04-install) --
in particular,

- Michiel Overtoom: [Installing Ubuntu with software RAID1 (mirroring)](http://www.michielovertoom.com/linux/ubuntu-software-raid/)

I think I have Ubuntu 14 now installed on my "md3" RAID partition.

The main chicken-and-egg problem is that the default Ubuntu 14 Desktop can't do RAID, so after it's installed on a RAID partition, it apparently can't boot.
After installing mdadm, it can handle RAID partitions fine -- but how to install mdadm when the OS won't even boot?

The main steps are:

- Prepare a Ubuntu USB stick and boot from it
- Use the "try Ubuntu" and open a terminal window.
- If you don't already have raw partitions set up, set them up with cfdisk or gparted.
- Install mdadm the first time -- on the USB stick -- with `apt-get install mdadm`
- If you don't already have the raw partitions raided together, do that now with `mdadm --create ...`
- Start the installer (icon on the LiveUSB desktop)
- Specify partitions manually, and pick the raid partition (in my case, `md3`), Use as Ext4, and mount it as "/". (I didn't seem to need a separate "/boot" partition, but that might be a quirk of my particular setup).
- IMPORTANT: On the last screen of the installer, choose "continue testing" (NOT "reboot"). If you race past this and try to boot off the hard drive, it won't work -- boot the LiveUSB image again and continue with the next step.
- While still running on the USB stick, install mdadm the second time -- on the hard drive -- with "chroot" and `apt-get install mdadm` (again).
- Copy the first part of the first hard disk to the second one using 'dd' -- the MBR, the GRUB boot loader, and the boot partition.
- `reboot`

Honestly, this seems unnecessarily complicated -- I will upvote anyone who posts a simpler answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/): The Lubuntu [Alternate ISO image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO) supports installing on RAID,
according to the [Lubuntu 14 release notes](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/).

After installation, you can later switch to whatever window manager / desktop environment you prefer -- see [Switching window manager/desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments) .